# Chrome browser: Facebook API Error Code: 191 when invoking Requests dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, heroku, apprequests, facebook-app-requests

I'm writing a Facebook canvas application that is using a basic Requests dialog. The dialog works fine when I call it from index.php, but I get Error 191 when I call the same code from any other file.  (In my case, the code is in file2.php, which is invoked from a form in index.php and is located in the same directory). The error appears only in Chrome, and not in Firefox or IE, where everything works fine.

Instead of seeing the request dialog, the user gets:
"API Error Code: 191
 API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application."

My configuration is as follows (please note that there is no spaces between "https:" and "//"):

App Domains: herokuapp.com

Hosting URL: https: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

Site URL: https: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

Canvas Page: http: //apps.facebook.com/mybrokenapp

Canvas URL: http: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

Secure Canvas URL: https: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

Page Tab URL: http: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

Secure Page Tab URL: https: //mybrokenapp.herokuapp.com/

The code that invokes the dialog:

```
      FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
         to: 'nnnnnnnnn',
             message : 'My message',
     show_error: true
            },
            function (response){
              if (typeof response == 'undefined')
        alert('Request failed');
      else if (response == null)
        alert('Request canceled');
      else
                alert('The response was' + response);
            }
           );
```

Could anyone tell me how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue in my app as well.

Go to your Channel.html that Facebook recommended adding, and change the javascript to:

```
<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

If you haven't added channel.html yet, you can also add that line in the head.

Chrome is much more strict about HTTPS than the other browsers.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I've changed my channel.html as recommended, but it didn't help - I got the same error. BTW, were you having that problem only in Chrome, as I did?

Comment: With your help I finally got it to work. It turned out that changing my channel.html wasn't enough in my case - I had a few lines "<script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> in my other .php files. I've changed them as well - and it worked. Thanks a lot! Do you have any ideas why the problem existed only in Chrome?